# "Recentf": Open file from *Open Recent* Buffer, but read-only

Tags: read-only-mode, recentf

I'm using recentf-mode, part of Emacs. I'd like to open a file from the *Open Recent* buffer read-only, like if I had opened it via C-x C-r. Maybe if you type C-u in the *Open Recent* buffer before clicking on the file or typing its number.

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it just as easy to use `C-x C-q` to make the visited buffer read-only as it is to use `C-u` before choosing it from the recent-buffers list?

Comment: @Drew Good idea, did not occur to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize `recentf-menu-action`, from `C-h v recentf-menu-action`:

> recentf-menu-action is a variable defined in ‘recentf.el’. Its value
>   is ‘find-file’
>
> Documentation: Function to invoke with a filename item of the recentf
>   menu. The default is to call ‘find-file’ to edit the selected file.

the default value is `find-file`, so if you always want read-only, you can just change it to `find-file-read-only`, if you only want read-only when with `C-u`, you can write a new function as its value, for example,

```el
(defun find-file-maybe-read-only (f)
  (if current-prefix-arg
      (find-file-read-only f)
    (find-file f)))

(setq recentf-menu-action 'find-file-maybe-read-only)
```

Notes: prefix arguments doesn't work for number, e.g., `C-u 2` doesn't work, though both `C-u RET` and `C-u Clicking` work.